# unable to extract subtitles into txt file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to extract subtitles to txt file

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -c copy -map 0:s:0 subs.txt
```

but get the following error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'subs.txt' 
subs.txt: Invalid argument
```

full console output:

```
ffmpeg version N-81872-gbe1d324 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.mkv':
  Metadata:
    CREATION_TIME   : 2018-10-28T02:41:51Z
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.7.2
  Duration: 00:11:45.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2774 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass
[NULL @ 00000000038c9540] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'subs.txt'
subs.txt: Invalid argument
```

It only works when I specify `ass` extension for output file like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -c copy -map 0:s:0 subs.ass
```

it extraxts properly and creates subs.ass file with subtitles
How ffmpeg interprets extension of output file?
Why do I have to specify exact extension for output file?

similar question, but different error here:
[ffmpeg unable to find a suitable output format for 'subs.srt'](https://superuser.com/questions/1456139/ffmpeg-unable-to-find-a-suitable-output-format-for-subs-srt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract subtitle from video using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/583393/how-to-extract-subtitle-from-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @JakeGould It's not a duplicate. The OP has already shown that using a different extension works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ffmpeg does not know what kind of output you want when supply a `.txt` file extension in the output path. Unless overridden by the `-f` option, it will try to figure out the necessary format from the file ending, so `.ass` will invoke the proper SSA format, `.srt` the SubRip format etc. The same goes for `.mp4`, `.mov`, etc.

To see what formats are supported, run `ffmpeg -formats`. There is no perfect mapping between format names and file extensions—sometimes there might be more than one extension triggering a format—, but in most cases they are the same. For example, the format `mp4` is called with a file ending `.mp4`, and the format `matroska` is called with `.mkv`.

As for your subtitles, you can force ffmpeg to use a given format with `-f <format>`. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0:s:0 -c copy -f srt output.txt
```

That assumes your input has SRT subtitles. If it doesn't, `-c copy` will not work. Leave out the `-c copy` part, for example, if you plan on outputting with `-f ass`.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the edit, but the capitalization was absolutely intended. I like to distinguish between “FFmpeg” (the software project) and “ffmpeg” (the command line tool). It sometimes helps disambiguate.

Comment: It is exactly what I have searched for. Command `ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -map 0:s:0 -f ass subs.txt` works as expected for my case